# JQuery :toggle images

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I would like to toggle photo by jQuery while I click on specific div  , I have two image (close1.gif and open.png), Now it's working just first time , close photo replace to open photo, but I want to replace open photo to close if I click on div again.
Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class=" server_Toggle subject-panel">
        <div>
                <p >server property</p><img alt="" src="images/close1.gif">
        </div>
            <ul id = "hidden_server">
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'server',
                        'action'     => 'index'
                    ),
                    'default',
                    true) ?>">  Server
                    </a>
                </li>
           </ul>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".server_Toggle").click(function(){
    $("#hidden_server").slideDown(1000);
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/open.png');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$(".server_Toggle").click(function () {
    $("#hidden_server").slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', function(i, src){
        return src == 'images/open.png' ? 'images/close1.gif' : 'images/open.png';
    });
});
```